How to disable concurrent job permanently
I want to disable a concurrent job permanently so that no one can execute it. Want to know what can be done for this.

Assuming you are running the jobs using dbms_scheduler then you can use dbms_scheduler.disable  to stop a job from running in the future.

What is "a concurrent job" exactly?
